Why $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(6n+1)^3}=\frac{1}{6^3}(91\zeta(3)+2\sqrt3\pi^3)$ is just the tip of the iceberg (Part 2)
(Continued from this post. Update: Section III below now includes the Glaisher H-numbers.)
I. Definitions
As before, given the Hurwitz zeta function,
$$\zeta(s,a) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac1{(k+a)^s}$$
define the zeta sums,
$$\zeta_s\big(a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots\big) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac1{(k+a_1)^s}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac1{(k+a_2)^s} + \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac1{(k+a_3)^s} +\dots$$
To address a comment, we will first focus on $3$rd powers, so $\zeta_\color{blue}3\big(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,\dots\big)$.

II. Level 7
Recall from the previous post that,
\begin{align}
A&=14^3\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac1{(14n+\color{red}1)^3}+\frac1{(14n+3)^3}+\frac1{(14n+5)^3}\right) = \frac{7}{2}(7^3-1)\,\zeta(3)+\frac{2\,x_1}{\sqrt{7}}\pi^3\\
B&=14^3\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac1{(14n+3)^3}+\frac1{(14n+\color{red}9)^3}+\frac1{(14n+13)^3}\right) = \frac{7}{2}(7^3-1)\,\zeta(3)+\frac{2\,x_2}{\sqrt{7}}\pi^3\\
C&=14^3\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac1{(14n+5)^3}+\frac1{(14n+\color{red}{11})^3}+\frac1{(14n+13)^3}\right) = \frac{7}{2}(7^3-1)\,\zeta(3)+\frac{2\,x_3}{\sqrt{7}}\pi^3
\end{align}
where $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ are the appropriate three roots of the cubic,
$$x^3 + 56x^2 - 3724x -208936 = 0$$
which seem(?) to be partly a consequence of the general identity,
$$\zeta(3,a)-\zeta(3,1-a)=\frac{\cos (a\pi)\;\;}{\big(\sin (a\pi)\big)^3}\,\pi^3$$
But the sum $A+B+C$ involves the value $x_1+x_2+x_3 = -56 = -7\times8$. So there must be a combination of zeta sums that do not use cubic roots. Thus, we have the simpler,
\begin{align}
14^3\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac1{(14n+\color{red}1)^3}+\frac1{(14n+\color{red}9)^3}+\frac1{(14n+\color{red}{11})^3}\right) &= \frac{7}{2}(7^3-1)\,\zeta(3)+16\sqrt{7}\,\pi^3\\
\zeta_3\left(\frac1{14},\frac9{14},\frac{11}{14}\right) &= \frac{7}{2}(7^3-1)\,\zeta(3)+16\sqrt{7}\,\pi^3
\end{align}
and its counterpart,
\begin{align}
14^3\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac1{(14n+3)^3}+\frac1{(14n+5)^3}+\frac1{(14n+13)^3}\right) &= \frac{7}{2}(7^3-1)\,\zeta(3)-16\sqrt{7}\,\pi^3\\
\zeta_3\left(\frac3{14},\frac5{14},\frac{13}{14}\right) &= \frac{7}{2}(7^3-1)\,\zeta(3)-16\sqrt{7}\,\pi^3
\end{align}

III. Family
For conciseness, using our zeta sum definition in Part I, then the family for prime $p=4n+3=3,7,11,19,$
\begin{align}
\zeta_3\left(\frac1{6}\right) &= \frac{7}{2}(3^3-1)\,\zeta(3)+\color{blue}1\times2\sqrt{3}\,\pi^3\\
\zeta_3\left(\frac1{14},\frac9{14},\frac{11}{14}\right) &= \frac{7}{2}(7^3-1)\,\zeta(3)+\color{blue}{8}\times2\sqrt{7}\,\pi^3\\
\zeta_3\left(\frac1{22},\frac3{22},\frac5{22},\frac{9}{22},\frac{15}{22}\right) &= \frac{7}{2}(11^3-1)\,\zeta(3)+\color{blue}{27}\times2\sqrt{11}\,\pi^3\\
\zeta_3\left(\frac1{38},\frac5{38},\frac7{38},\frac{9}{38},\frac{11}{38},\frac{17}{38},\frac{23}{38},\frac{25}{38},\frac{35}{38}\right)  &= \frac{7}{2}(19^3-1)\,\zeta(3)+\color{blue}{99}\times2\sqrt{19}\,\pi^3
\end{align}
and so on.
(Update, Aug 29.) We have factored out the multiple of $2$ since it turns out $\zeta_s\big(\frac16\big)$ for odd $s>1$ involves what are called the Glaisher H'-numbers, namely
$$H'(s) = 1,11,301,15371,\dots$$
So for $s=5$,
$$\zeta_5\left(\frac1{6}\right) = \frac{(2^5-1)(3^5-1)}2\,\zeta(5)+\frac{11\times2}{\sqrt{3}}\,\pi^5$$
See also this new post.

IV. Questions
The blue integers continue as $c = (1, 8, 27, 99, 168, 336, 747, 1008, 1809).$ And, no, they are not in the OEIS. Q1: So anybody knows if they have a closed-form?
These correspond to primes $p=4n+3 = (3, 7, 11, 19, 23, 31, 43, 47, 59).$ Q2: And how do we derive the $a_i$ of $\zeta_s\big(a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots\big)$ from first principles? (Not using integer relations algorithm.)

@Zima It is $\zeta_s(a_1,a_2,...,a_n) = \zeta(s,a_1) + \zeta(s,a_2) + \dots + \zeta(s,a_n)$. In this post, I only use 3rd powers, so $s=3$, thus always $\zeta_{\color{red}3}(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)$. I may revise the post to emphasize this.

(This answer is inspired by the previous post.) For prime $p = 4n+3$, given the fractions $a_k$ as,

T_p = Sort[Table[Mod[(2k - 1)^2, 2p], {k, 1, (p-1)/2}] / (2p)]

An example by WolframAlpha is here. Then define the function,
$$F_p(a_1, a_2, a_3,\dots) = \frac{1}{4\sqrt{p}}\sum_{k=1}^{(p-1)/2}\frac{\cos(a_k\,\pi)}{\sin^3(a_k\,\pi)}$$
Then it turns out that,
\begin{align}
F_3 \left(\frac16\right) &=\frac{1}{4\sqrt{3}}\left(\frac{\cos(\frac{\pi}6)}{\sin^3(\frac{\pi}6)}\right) = \color{blue}1\\
F_7 \left(\frac1{14},\frac{9}{14},\frac{11}{14}\right) &=
\frac{1}{4\sqrt{7}}\left(\frac{\cos(\frac{\pi}{14})}{\sin^3(\frac{\pi}{14})}+\frac{\cos(\frac{9\pi}{14})}{\sin^3(\frac{9\pi}{14})}+\frac{\cos(\frac{11\pi}{14})}{\sin^3(\frac{11\pi}{14})}\right) = \color{blue}{8}\\
F_{11} \left(\frac1{22},\frac{3}{22},\frac{5}{22}, \frac{9}{22}, \frac{15}{22}\right) &=
\frac{1}{4\sqrt{11}}\left(\frac{\cos(\frac{\pi}{22})}{\sin^3(\frac{\pi}{22})}+\frac{\cos(\frac{3\pi}{22})}{\sin^3(\frac{3\pi}{22})}+\dots+\frac{\cos(\frac{15\pi}{22})}{\sin^3(\frac{15\pi}{22})}\right) = \color{blue}{27}
\end{align}
with the next one as $F_{19}=\color{blue}{99}$, and so on. So the blue integers do have a closed-form in terms of trigonometric functions. Thus, the family in Part III can be nicely expressed as,
$$\zeta_3(a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots) = \frac{7}{2}(p^3-1)\,\zeta(3)+2\sqrt{p}\,F_p(a_1, a_2, a_3,\dots)\,\pi^3$$
Or equivalently,
$$\sum_{k=1}^{(p-1)/2}\zeta(3,a_k) = \frac{7}{2}(p^3-1)\,\zeta(3)+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{(p-1)/2}\frac{\cos(a_k\pi)}{\sin^3(a_k\pi)}\,\pi^3$$
These results were serendipitously observed days after the original post. They address both questions: whether $F_p(a_1,a_2,\dots)$ has a closed-form, and whether the $a_k$ can be derived without using integer-relations.
P.S. However, what arises are missing pieces of the puzzle: to rigorously show why the modular arithmetic approach works so well, and why it fails for prime $p=4m+1$ (since then it has $F_p = 0$). For example,
$$F_{13} \left(\frac1{26},\frac{3}{26},\frac{9}{26}, \frac{17}{26}, \frac{23}{26}, \frac{25}{26}\right) = 0$$
though one can quickly observe that $1+25 = 3+23 = 9+17 = 26$, relations that do not occur for primes $p=4m+3$.
